# How to get index value from the auto complete text view adapter

Tags: list, autocompletetextview

I am having an `AutoCompleteTextView` and data was populated using custom adapter for `AutoCompleteTextView`.Here i am having 1000 entries(NAME------VALUE) in a list and I need to get the value of the selected item(NAME).But here when i selected the value which was filtered from the `AutoCompleteText` its starting position was taking from 0

```
 Clear example


        My auto complete list entries:

Name1---------------value1
Name2---------------value2
Name3---------------value3
Name4---------------value4
Name5---------------value5
Name6---------------value6
      -
      -
      -
      -
      -
Name96---------------value96
Name97---------------value97
Name98---------------value98
Name99---------------value99
```

if i set the threshold value for `AutoCompleteTextView` to 2 if i was entered text and i  am getting some Name-----values `list`from 50-60.If i selected NAME50----VALUE50 of dropdown menu of `AutoCompleteTextView` which was located at the first of the filtered values its position was taking as 0.But i want its original list location of NAME50----VALUE50 i.e 49 and its corresponding values. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this.
Sorry for my bad explanation and english

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ArrayList in your ArrayAdapter

```
yourTextViewName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id) {

      int iPos = yourListViewName.indexOf(yourTextViewName.getText().toString());
      Toast.makeText(mContext, "Selected item index "+iPos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
});
```